# How can I select last two dates in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I have list of dates 1st Nov 2018 to 9th Nov 2018. Now in Power BI I want to compare data of last two dates 8th Nov 2018 vs 9th Nov 2018.
I have tried putting date column in visual filter so that I can choose max two dates, but date filter is now appearing in that filter.
Kindly help

Comment: Please, provide some code.

Comment: This question is hard to answer, as there are a lot of important details missing. Try to put yourself in the shoes of those who know nothing about your problem. Make sure to [edit] your question to include all **relevant** content. Providing a [mcve] will increase your chances of getting good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the date column to the **Visual level filters**, you can change the **Filter Type** to **Relative date filtering** and specify **is in the last 2 days**.